# How to store a variable in a .txt file and use it in multiple workbooks to auto-fill a userform text box

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I have created a userform to save and print paperwork with incremented serial numbers on each copy. The userform prompts the user for the next available serial number and how many copies to create. Once the user clicks the "create" button it fills in a cell, saves a new copy, prints the copy, then adds 1 to the serial number before looping. What I want to do is store the final serial number in a .txt file saved in the network folder, and then retrieve that number in another workbook to autofill the serial number text box in the userform. Is this possible? Can a variale be used to autofill a userform text box?

Module to open useform:

```
Sub start()
    '''Retrieve stored serial number to autofill userform'''
    WO_BulkCreate.Show
End Sub
```

[image]

Code for userform buttons (nextWOnumber and createAmount comefrom the userform text boxes):

```
Private Sub Cancel_Click()
    Unload WO_BulkCreate
End Sub

Private Sub Create_Click()
    'Variables
    Dim Amount As Integer                        'Number of WOs to be created
    Dim WO_Name As String                        'WO number
    Dim i As Integer                             'loop tracker
    Dim saveName As String                       'New File Name

    'initialize variables
    Amount = createAmount
    i = 0

    'Begin loop
    Do While i < Amount

        'Assemble WO number and filename
        WO_Name = "Customer Code-" & nextWOnumber
        saveName = WO_Name & " - part number - part description"

        'Update WO number Cell
        Sheets("WO Charge Sheet").Range("WO") = WO_Name

        'Save New Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\filepath\" & saveName

        'Set orientation to landscape
        Worksheets("WO Charge Sheet").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
        Worksheets("Ops Planning").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape

        'Print WO
        Sheets(Array("WO Charge Sheet", "Ops Planning")).PrintOut

        'Increment WO number
        nextWOnumber = nextWOnumber + 1

        'Step loop
        i = i + 1

        'End loop
    Loop

    '''Store final serial number in text file'''

    'Close form
    Unload WO_BulkCreate
End Sub
```

I hope that makes sense. Sorry if this is tmi, this is my first time posting on SO

Bread Doughlas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the way I solved this problem.

Storing the Variable:

```
'Store next serial number
    Dim fileNo As Integer, serialNo As String

    fileNo = FreeFile

    Open "C:\filepath\nextSerialNumber.txt" For Output As #fileNo
    Write #fileNo, serialNo; 'I had to add this semicolon to prevent it from writing a linebreak

'Close file
    Close #fileNo
```

This worked to store my variable, but it did add a comma after it. I was able to find a workaround for the comma in my code for retrieving the variable:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Variables
    Dim serialNo As String, fileNo As Integer

'Intialize
    fileNo = FreeFile

'Read next serial number
    Open "C:\filepath\nextSerialNumber.txt" For Input As #fileNo
    serialNo = Input$(LOF(fileNo), fileNo)

'Remove Comma
    If (Right(serialNo, 1)) = "," Then
        serialNo = Left(serialNo, Len(serialNo) - 1)
    End If

'Fill Text Boxes
    nextSerialNumber.Value = serialNo

'End Read File
    Close #fileNo

End Sub
```

This works great for me, hope it helps ppl in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work but you need to be aware of possible contention issues which would require a slightly more complex approach, possible using a "lock" file to ensure only one user can read at a time...

```
Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print NextSequence()
End Sub


Function NextSequence() As String
    Const SEQ_FILE As String = "C:\Tester\seq.txt" '<<location of the sequence file
    Dim txt As String, seq As Long
    With CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        If .fileexists(SEQ_FILE) Then  '<< does the file exist ?
            txt = Trim(.opentextfile(SEQ_FILE, 1).readall())
            If IsNumeric(txt) Then
                seq = CLng(txt)
            End If
        Else
            seq = 1  '<< no file yet, start with 1
        End If
        With .createtextfile(SEQ_FILE)
            .writeline seq + 1 '<<write the next sequence
        End With
    End With
    NextSequence = seq
End Function
```